# Spring social type mismatch error while twitter API binding

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-social

I am following the [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/apis.html#twitter-search) to implement a twitter search on Spring framework. Unfortunately, I get an type mismatch error in here:

```
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
 ...
Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate();

Type mismatch: cannot convert from TwitterTemplate to Twitter
```

Why am I getting this error? Should I just simply add a casting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported the wrong `Twitter` class.

use

```
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter
```

instead.

@see [Java Doc: Twiter Template](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/impl/TwitterTemplate.html)